# Libre Office CheckBox1, macro variable

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, libreoffice-basic

How to get the value from CheckBox1 from the dialog in librecalc? I need to put this value in a variable,
I searched on the forum but did not find it
 please help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with a code like this

```
Sub Check1
  If Dlg.GetControl("CheckBox1").State = 1 then
      msgbox("OK")  
  else
      msgbox("NO")
  End If
End Sub
```